# Turn windows features on and off empty list

Tags: asp.net, windows, visual-studio

After my VS2017 setup finished, fellow warning occurred :

> Couldn't install Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNet45.Feature

After one day search I understood the problem is related to windows features.
when I open the "Turn Windows features on or off" windows , there ware not any lists in it.
How can I access to windows features list ?
My OS is Windows 10.